# GridView.count() not updating when values changed in cron

Tags: flutter, gridview, dart, cron, future

**What I'm trying to do**

What I'm trying to do is retrieve data from an API call and pass the data in the response to a `GridView.count()` widget every minute because the data could change.

I did this using a `FutureBuilder` widget and the `Cron` functionality from the **cron/cron.dart** if that helps.

Here is the code:

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
    future: Api.getFoods(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
        List<Widget> slots = [];

        if (snapshot.data == null) {
        return Text('');
        }

        var data = snapshot.data;
        cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/1 * * * *'), () async {
            setState(() {
                data = snapshot.data;
            });
            slots = [];
        });

        for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.length; i++) {
            slots.add(new FoodSlot(
                snapshot.data[i]['name'],
                snapshot.data[i]['created_at'],
                snapshot.data[i]['qty'].toString()
            ));
        }

        return new GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            children: slots
        );
})
```

The `FoodSlot` widget creates a `Card` and displays the value passed in the arguments on the card.

**What I tried**

After debugging, I saw that the cron job works fine, but the `GridView` widgets just won't update.

I tried using a `Text` widget instead of the `GridView` and return the values returned by the API call and the widget is updated automatically every 1 minute as expected.

Why is `GridView.count()` acting like this and how can I fix this?

---

**UPDATE**

When the changes in the database are made, the GridView does update, but only when the application is restarted (using R not r).

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Turns out I had to add the cron job in the `FoodSlot` widget and update the widget itself periodically.

Ended up adding the following in the `initState()` function for `FoodSlot`:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    colorSettings = HelperFunctions.setStateColour(expiry);

    cron.schedule(new Schedule.parse('*/1 * * * *'), () async {
      setState(() {
        Api.getFood(id).then((res) {
          expiry = res['created_at'];
          name = res['name'];
          qty = res['qty'].toString();
          colorSettings = HelperFunctions.setStateColour(expiry);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Where `id` is the id of the database entry referenced by the `FoodSlot` widget.

Hope this helps someone :)